# Google Cloud Function - Python script to get data from Webhook

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, webhooks

I hope someone can help me out on my problem.

I have a google-cloud function created which is http triggered and a webhook setup in customer.io

I need to capture data that was sent by customer.io app. this should trigger the google cloud function and run the python script setup within the cloud function. I am new to writing python script and its libraries. The final goal is to write the webhook data into bigquery table.

For now, I am able to see that trigger is working since I am seeing the data using print sent by the app using the function logs. I am able to check the schema of the data as well from the logs in textpayload.

This is the sample data from the textpayload I wanted to load on a bigquery table:

```json
{
   "data":{
      "action_id":42,
      "campaign_id":23,
      "customer_id":"user-123",
      "delivery_id":"RAECAAFwnUSneIa0ZXkmq8EdkAM==-",
      "identifiers":{
         "id":"user-123"
      },
      "recipient":"test@example.com",
      "subject":"Thanks for signing up"
   },
   "event_id":"01E2EMRMM6TZ12TF9WGZN0WJaa",
   "metric":"sent",
   "object_type":"email",
   "timestamp":1669337039
}
```

and this is the sample Python code I have created on the google-cloud function:

```py
import os

def webhook(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request_json)
        return 'success'
    else:
        return 'failed'
```

I have only tried printing the data from webhook and what I am expecting is to have a Python code that writes this textpayload data into bigquery table.

```json
{
   "data":{
      "action_id":42,
      "campaign_id":23,
      "customer_id":"user-123",
      "delivery_id":"RAECAAFwnUSneIa0ZXkmq8EdkAM==-",
      "identifiers":{
         "id":"user-123"
      },
      "recipient":"test@example.com",
      "subject":"Thanks for signing up"
   },
   "event_id":"01E2EMRMM6TZ12TF9WGZN0WJaa",
   "metric":"sent",
   "object_type":"email",
   "timestamp":1669337039
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have up a cloud function that executes some code whenever the webhook posts some data to it.

What this cloud function needs now is the BigQuery python client library. Here's an example of how it's used ([source](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/index.html?utm_source=googleapisdev&utm_medium=banner#perform-a-query)):

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

dataset_id = ...
table_name = ...
data = ... 

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_name)
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
result = client.insert_rows(table, data)
```

So you could put something like this into your cloud function in order to send your data to a target BigQuery table.

Comment: I understand some of the code part but correct me if I'm wrong. The parameters are:
dataset_id = <dataset name>
table_name = <table name>

data = ???
where and how should I get this if data is coming from post triggered by webhook request?
also I am not seeing a project id, will this work without it? Thanks!

Comment: You must have set up a GCP project or else you couldn't have a cloud function and a BigQuery instance. If you're sending data to BigQuery, there needs to be a table to receive it, and tables live in datasets. You need to create a table (and a dataset) in BigQuery to receive the data. You will choose the dataset and table names when you do that. The project ID will appear as the parent folder for the datasets in BigQuery, it'll usually look like `random-words-123456`. The three together tell your cloud function _where_ to send the data.

Comment: Yeah, those were setup. I am asking on the code part. I have a project, a dataset, and a table with one column with json data type. How will I put this on the python code and tell to put the json post request on this table? Forgive me, I am new and trying to learn python.

Comment: Okay. The dataset and table names are just strings, so `dataset_id = "whatever-your-dataset-id-is"` in the example code. The project ID gets used in the background (so long as your cloud function and BigQuery instance are part of the same GCP project, you'll probably be fine). The `data` variable will just be your `request_json`, possibly with some transformation into whatever format BigQuery needs (this may take some reading + experimentation).

Comment: Ultimately you _are_ going to have to read [the client library documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html) - StackOverflow is best used for specific questions with a limited scope, whereas it sounds like you need a tutorial.